# How to parse commands from a text file to a bash script in the CLI

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a bash script which getting the data by this:

```
$ ./script.sh var1 var2 var3
```

What I want is to have the variables in a text file in the same format like I type in the command line.

input.txt

```
var1 var2 var3
```

And I want somehow to feed this txt to my bash script in the command line, not in the bash script:

```
./script.sh input.txt
```

How is it possible?

Update:

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

DOMAINS=( '.com' '.biz' )

VALUE=$(<input.txt)
INPUT=(`echo "$VALUE"`)

ELEMENTS=${#DOMAINS[@]}

while (( "$#" )); do

  for (( i=0;i<$ELEMENTS;i++)); do
      whois $1${DOMAINS[${i}]} | grep --perl-regexp --text --null --only-matching --quiet 'Creation Date'
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo -e "$1${DOMAINS[${i}]}\tregistered\t"
    else
        echo -e "$1${DOMAINS[${i}]}\tavailable\t"
    fi
  done

shift

done
```

As you can see, I tried to implement in the script also, but I'm not a programmer.

The perfect solution would be to remove the used data from input.txt. So if it reads var1 from input.txt, than remove it from there! This can be solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various ways to do this. If your script doesn't need to take more than one argument, just use a `while` loop to read the file. I would also remove some of the needless `grep` options (you don't need `--only--matching` when using `--quiet`, you're never seeing the output; you don't need perl regex since you're not using any of their features and you don't need `--text` since you're not going to be parsing binary files) and using the shorter option names for brevity.

So, a working (and slightly improved) version of your script would be:

```
#!/bin/bash

DOMAINS=( '.com' '.biz' )

while read input; do
    for (( i=0;i<${#DOMAINS[@]};i++)); do
    whois "$input${DOMAINS[$i]}" | grep -q 'Creation Date'
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            echo -e "$input${DOMAINS[$i]}\tregistered\t"
    else
            echo -e "$input${DOMAINS[$i]}\tavailable\t"
    fi
    done
done < "$1"
```

If you run that on a file containing:

```
google
foogle
```

You get:

```
$ foo.sh file
google.com  registered  
google.biz  available   
gaagle.com  registered  
gaagle.biz  available
```

Comment: I got the following error when I try to run this script: `-bash: ./script.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`. The command was: `./script.sh input.txt`. Input.txt is in the same folder just like the bash script.

Comment: If I change the headline to this `#!/usr/bin/env bash` than I got the following error: `: No such file or directory`

Comment: @user1442219 you're working on a Windows system then, or edited the file on Windows. Don't. That inserted a carriage return character (`\r`) which is needed to define newlines in Windows (they use `\r\n` while *nix uses `\n`). To fix it, run `sed -i 's/\r//g' script.sh` and then try again.

Comment: Sorry, that was the problem. I forget to set the line endings on the new file where I copied your script. Works great!

Comment: you might just do: `for i in .com .biz; do ...`. that could be a little more simple. why assign to an array to iterate that array when the `for` incorporates an array assignment in the syntax?